Coldfusion page display issue with First Nations/Indigenous characters/fonts (unicode?)
When I save the following content as a .html file, it renders the characters properly when I save the same file with a .cfm file extensions it renders it with odd characters.
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
Tḱemlúps te Secwépemc territory
</body>
</html>

Is there something that needs to be configured on the Coldfusion to make it work? It currently looks like this saved as a .cfm file:

Looks like this saved as a .html file:

Is there something I am missing?

I think it is your editor which will change the default encoding. Check in your editor (maybe in view) which encoding is using in one case and in the other), in any case it should not matter for other programs

If you are seeing the invalid characters in the browser when you render the cfm file,
try adding this -Dfile.encoding=utf8 to the jvm.config (JVM Arguments in CF admin). Link

Cold fusion is defaulting your page to iso-8859-1 or Windows-1252. If you Dave your file as UTF-8 with BOM will it render correctly?

<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">

Use this in the cfm page.

Adding  to the page worked! Tried rrk's suggestion too but was waiting for the right time to restart our CF server to test it. Here is rrk's suggestion if the link doesn't work: Log into the CF Admin
Under Server Settings click Java and JVM.
Under JVM Arguments add: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
Restart the server and the page will display unicode. According to the link, setting the encoding in the  of your document is for the web browser to know how to render the content. Setting the processing directive is to tell CF how to compile the file.
